# How to get information with AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, oop

I try to get information with ajax from my php class but it doesn't work.

PHP Static class:

```
static public function showOnlineUsers() {
    $db = Db::getInstance();
    $time = time() + (24 * 60 * 60);
    $sql = 'SELECT * `'._DB_PREFIX_.'prestaChat_users` WHERE `lastActivity`="1333333092"';
    $users = $db->ExecuteS($sql);
    $count = count($users);
    throw new Exception($users);
}
```

Ajax php file:

```
require "prestaChat.php";

$type = strtolower($_POST['type']);
$array = array('getusers', 'getmessages');

if(in_array($type, $array)) {
//    switch($type) {
//        case 'getusers': prestaChat::showOnlineUsers();
//            break;
//    }
    try {
        prestaChat::showOnlineUsers();
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        print_r($exc->getMessage());
    }

}
```

jQuery $.ajax query:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'modules/prestaChat/ajax.php',
    data: {'type': 'getusers'},
    success: function(asd) {
        console.log(asd);
    }
});
```

So where is the false? I'm newbie in object-oriented php and last ajax thing which I create with jquery (ajax) and oop php works fine, but it send information doesn't get it...

Comment: what doesn't work? Not getting response? Or getting 500 in your ajax or..? There's a plethora of possibilities, help us help you

Comment: not getting response... when I try to catch the code - i catch it, but when I try with the message it doesn't work... :(

Answer (score 0):

I recently had issues using ajax and couldn't find the false for awhile.  I don't know if the same reason I was getting mine, is why you are getting yours but I had my handler php file/script in the same directory as my javascript file calling the handler so I put my url as 'handler.php' but that was actually wrong.  Even though they were in the same folder, the main script evoking those scripts was not in the js folder so I needed to change my url to 'js/handler.php' and it worked.

Like I said, I dunno if this is the case from what you presented, but the hierarchy is worth looking at.

Comment: The folders and paths are okey, but the response isn't :)